# REGEXP_REPLACE Strings Starting and Ending with Specific Substrings in Snowflake

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-replace

I am trying to create a column in a view in Snowflake that replaces any string between strings that I care about with nothing.

This is essentially for the purpose of stripping html formatting out of text.
As an example:

```
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Text I care about 1
&lt;li&gt;Text I care about 2&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Text I care about 3&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
```

Would should end up like this:

```
Text I care about 1
Text I care about 2
Text I care about 3
```

Based on the patterns I am seeing, I think that if I can eliminate any string starting with &lt, and ending with >, I should be able to achieve the result I am looking for.

In testing on different sites it seems like expression
`REGEXP_REPLACE(originaltext, '&lt.+?&gt;','')` should, work, but when attempting in Snowflake it seems to be cutting off the last 'Text I care about' in some cases, and in other cases just is not showing any results at all. I am not sure if there is a syntax difference or something else off in the version of regex snowflake is using, but any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression works, but it requires lookarounds.

```
set sample1 = '&lt;ul&gt;';
set sample2 = '&lt;li&gt;Text I care about 1';
set sample3 = '&lt;li&gt;Text I care about 2&lt;/li&gt;';
set sample4 = '&lt;li&gt;Text I care about 3&lt;/li&gt;';
set sample5 = '&lt;/ul&gt;';

select regexp_replace2($SAMPLE1,'&lt.+?&gt;','');  
select regexp_replace2($SAMPLE2,'&lt.+?&gt;','');
select regexp_replace2($SAMPLE3,'&lt.+?&gt;','');
select regexp_replace2($SAMPLE4,'&lt.+?&gt;','');
select regexp_replace2($SAMPLE5,'&lt.+?&gt;','');
```

I wrote a UDF library that supports regular expression lookarounds. It attempts to approximate the built-in Snowflake regular expression functions while supporting lookarounds. The names of the UDFs are the same as the built-in regular expression functions with the suffix "2" as shown in the SQL sample.

https://github.com/GregPavlik/SnowflakeUDFs/tree/main/RegularExpressions

Comment: Perfect! I will spend some more time familiarizing myself with lookarounds and what your code is doing, but it does exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant, but if you know all the special encodings you want to remove, maybe you can just list them like that?

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('&lt;li&gt;Text I care about 3&lt;/li&gt;', '(&lt;)|(li&gt;)|(/li&gt;)','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your challenge is the fact that you are using a LAZY quantifier (**.+?**) and Snowflake doesn't supports it as according to our [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#general-usage-notes):

```
Patterns support the full POSIX ERE (Extended Regular Expression) syntax. For details, see the POSIX basic and extendedsection (in Wikipedia).
```

The Wikipedia link shows that **LAZY** is **NOT** covered by the ERE standard, but is it an extension.

In your case you could maybe use a **REGEXP_SUBSTR**, like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('&lt;li&gt;Text I care about 1&lt;/li&gt;', '(\\w+\\s)+\\d');
```

with output like:

```
Text I care about 1
```

but this requires a specific pattern on your data.